# how to create virtual column on Doctrine Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

how to create virtual column on Doctrine Symfony2

i have two table

```
table Company
---------------------------------
id  | company_name      | address
---------------------------------
1   | sample Co Ltd     | NY
2   | company Co Ltd    | LA
---------------------------------

table Ships
---------------------------------
id  | company_id    | ships_name
---------------------------------
1   | 1             | Ship ABC
1   | 1             | Ship XYZ
---------------------------------
```

how to create query with virtual column (total_ships) in doctrine symfony2, so i can display with data like this in twig template:

```
{% for entity in pagination %}
   <tr>
    <td>{{ entity.company_name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ entity.total_ships }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Can i add query on Entity Class of Company?
Please give me a clue,
Thanks
Best Regards,
Rampak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the Entities relationship in their Entity classes.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

and

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

When you have done that and updated your schema, you can do this in Twig:

```
{{ company.ships|length }}
```

To get a count.
You can also do any type of operatios like

All you need to do is pass a Company object to Twig and Twig + Doctrine will handle everything for you.

Comment: I tried extend Twig Extension and using Doctrine Repository, and its works, thank you